"Drizzle Kit Migration: PostgresError 'password authentication failed for user' during database migration"
after connecting all setup with supabase as shown in this youtube chanel text  timing 1:30:30 database setup its throwing error :- > dashboard@0.1.0 db:migrate

drizzle-kit migrate

No config path provided, using default 'drizzle.config.ts'Reading config file 'E:\assignme 2\person2\S-x3\x_up\feed2\dashboard\drizzle.config.ts'Using 'postgres' driver for database querying[⣟] applying migrations...PostgresError: password authentication failed for user "AKANSHA DEO SHIVANSH"at ErrorResponse (file:///E:/assignme%202/person2/S-x3/x_up/feed2/dashboard/node_modules/postgres/src/connection.js:788:26)at handle (file:///E:/assignme%202/person2/S-x3/x_up/feed2/dashboard/node_modules/postgres/src/connection.js:474:6)at Socket.data (file:///E:/assignme%202/person2/S-x3/x_up/feed2/dashboard/node_modules/postgres/src/connection.js:315:9)at Socket.emit (node:events:514:28)at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:343:12)at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:316:9)at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:253:10)at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)at TCP.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {severity_local: 'FATAL',severity: 'FATAL',code: '28P01',file: 'auth.c',line: '326',routine: 'auth_failed'}

please anyone give me solution or tell me where i am making mistake

since you did not provide config file the system is using the default one which is drizzle.config.ts you need to edit this file and make sure you've added correct mysql connection host+database name+password .
becouse the error also saying password authentication failed for user "AKANSHA DEO SHIVANSH". which is means the database username or password are wrong .
just make sure you add correct database information in this file
